# Getting an Array of objects using JSON with WHERE clause coming from an Android App

Tags: php, android, json

I need to get this array of objects from a php file to be transfered in my android app. My php file has no errors and capable of fetching data with `WHERE` clauses. My problem is that I need to fetch a data from my app in order to use as a where clause in my php file.

I used 3 classes in order to serve as a dataparser, downloader, cursoradapter(not important).

**PHP Part:**

```
        case 'getMsg':
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'u499431357_pg1';
        $pass = 'preggorie';
        $db = 'u499431357_pg1';

            $idPreg = (int)($_GET['idPreg']);
            $con = mysqli_connect ($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die ('Unable to Connect');

            if (mysqli_connect_error ($con)){
                echo "Failed to connect";
            }

            $query = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT * FROM msgPreg where pregId = '$idPreg'");

            if ($query){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query)){
                    $flag [] = $row;
                }
                print (json_encode($flag));
            }
                mysqli_close($con);

            break;
```

**Downloader:**

http://pastebin.com/xRHU0FEM

**DataParser:**

http://pastebin.com/tUZ9GM66

** I don't know where to put the id that I need in order to get it from my php file. Please help :(

Answer (score 1):

just put the id in the end ofurl like this:

```
http://example.com/getData?idPred=10
```

Comment: so you can do this: preggorie.hol.es/addToCart.php?action=getMsg&idPreg=10

Comment: Hi faraz, this is not what I need but I found a answer in youtube already. Thanks for your effort :)